# Tomcat thread control

Tags: multithreading, tomcat

I have two tomcat servers running at the same time. I have reports which are requested from server 1 sent to server 2 for processing. So how would I go about managing the threads on server 2? For example, if I wanted to queue up the threads how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a message queue (like [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)) in the middle to queue up the tasks that need to be done.

Then, your report generating server can pull jobs from the queue and work on them. If you need to slow down or speed up, then you can increase the number of "workers" running.

Comment: is there a way to do it without using third party software? like what if i wanted to write my own api for handling the threads? how would i go about doing that?

Comment: Ultimately, if you want to have a queue to store jobs flowing between two processes, you need to have that queue built in such a way that the consumer has control over it, and the producer needs to submit jobs asynchronously. RabbitMQ uses the standard AMQP protocol to communicate, so you could easily use that same protocol as your "api". JMS is another java-centric spec in the same space, but it is much less widely used.